# How to send SQSMessage consumed from SQSQueue directly to DLQ (C#)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to send an SQSMessage that is consumed from a SQSEvent.Records list explicitly to a DLQ. I understand that I can send it to the queue like any normal queue as long as the queueClient is pointing the DLQ.

The part I am having trouble with is that the SendMessageRequest object (which the queueClient publishes) only has a parameter for the string messageBody. I however have an SQSMessage object and would like to persist all the metadata as well. I feel if I just use the Body property of the SQSMessage object, all the metadata will be lost? (MessageId, EventSource, MessageAttributes) etc

Comment: You are correct. You can't preserve the metadata, unless you embed it in a body.

Comment: What if you do not delete the message after the processing and set the Queue configuration (Maximum receives) to move message to DLQ after 1 receive. This will push to message to DLQ once the message is processed without you doing it manually.

Comment: @Chetan there are some use cases where we want to keep the retry on the SQS level for messages. but for other use cases we want to directly publish to DLQ as we dont want to retry for thos cases

Comment: @Marcin does the metadata get preserved when the message is sent to the DLQ through the SQS level (implicitly through maximum recieves)? i would assume so, but my familiarity is lacking

Comment: Probably not, but you can test it easily. Setup some queue + DLQ and check how it works.

Comment: `I am trying to send an SQSMessage that is consumed from a SQSEvent.Records list explicitly to a DLQ.` - why?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary there are some use cases where we want to keep the retry on the SQS level for messages. but for other use cases we want to directly publish to DLQ as we dont want to retry for thos cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQS+DLQ it won't change the metadata of the message.
Also, if your case is just to delay the message why not use Visibility Timeout
like 0 to make DLQ movement faster or say close to 12 hr to consume the message slower.